# Calculate difference in seconds

Tags: google-sheets

```
Duur            Resultaat

17:09:31.228    17:09:38.555    
17:09:56.635    17:10:02.811    
17:10:17.637    17:10:23.954    
17:10:35.246    17:10:41.723    
17:12:23.912    17:12:30.699    
17:11:39.064    17:11:45.251    
17:15:00.119    17:15:06.055    
17:17:28.066    17:17:28.897    
17:18:05.336    17:18:06.107
```

How can I get the difference in seconds between the two timestamps? 
For the first row if need to have 7.327 as result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Duur` is ColumnA, `Resultaat` is ColumnB and ColumnsA:C are formatted hh:mm:ss.000 then in C2:

```
=B2-A2
```

should result in `00:00:07.327`.